# Is identical data okay to run apriori algorithm?

Tags: python, associations, apriori

### Hi I'm trying to generate small virtual dataset for association rules analysis using apriori algorithm.
And I'm wondering if it matters when there's same data in the dataset.
For example, [milk,milk,banana,yogurt], [apple, meat, soap, apple]
Thanks for reading!

Here's what i've coded so far

1. generate random sample (weighted)

   products = ['홈','어웨이','마킹','입장용트랙탑(블랙)','레인자켓(블랙)','레인자켓(레드)','패딩수트상의(블랙)','패딩수트상의(레드)','선수단롱다운(블랙)','패딩베스트(블랙)','이동복상의(블랙)','이동복상의(블랙)',
   '트레이닝상의(블랙)','트레이닝상의(레드)','바람막이피스테(블랙)','바람막이피스테(레드)','연습복긴팔(블랙)','연습복긴팔(레드)',
   '연습복반팔(블랙)','연습복반팔(레드)','폴로티긴팔(블랙)','폴로티긴팔(레드)','폴로티반팔(블랙)','폴로티반팔(레드)','트레이닝하의(블랙)','3/4팬츠(블랙)',
   '연습복반바지(블랙)','응원용품','FC서울로고니트머플러','FC서울SoulofSeoul니트머플러','FC서울브랜딩니트머플러','FC서울WHITE니트머플러',
   '서울오리지널머플러','기성용캡틴머플러','전사골드머플러','전사블랙머플러','아동유니폼','선수단볼캡블랙','선수단볼캡레드','선수단동계비니','40주년백구','선수단신발주머니','FC서울MINI레인보우',
   'FC서울포토레인보우','유니폼뱃지','엠블럼뱃지','레터링뱃지']
   #총 47개
   prob=[0.2454,0.0966,0.2316,0.0026,0.0031,0.0016,0.0027,0.0001,0.0033,0.0003,0.0021,0.0004,0.0010,0.0017,0.0013,0.0034,0.0011,
   0.0029,0.0030,0.0024,0.0007,0.0009,0.0023,0.0006,0.0014,0.0019,0.0020,0.0368,0.0174,0.0464,0.0116,0.0058,0.0232,
   0.0406,0.0348,0.0291,0.0107,0.0231,0.0069,0.0208,0.0162,0.0046,0.0093,0.0116,0.0185,0.0023,0.0139]

random_data = np.random.choice(products, size=50000,p=prob)

---

2. Generate 1000 customers list, I tried to solve the redundancy with set(list_random) but It doesn't follow the weights of sample above

   store=[]
   for i in range(1,1000):
   for j in range(random.randint(1,4)):
   randsample=random.sample(set(list_random),j)
   store.append(randsample)
   #print(store)

   df = pd.DataFrame(store)
   df.head(10)

---

(I thought there shouldn't be same data in the dataset for apriori algorithm
But I ran the algorithm with dataset that has same data, it worked.)

Comment: Oops! sorry I just edited my post